# How to unambiguously overload a function that has an std::size_t template parameter and one that has a scoped enum template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, ambiguous, overload-resolution

In a vector class I'm providing two ways to access the components with compile-time checking of bounds:

```cpp
...

        template<std::size_t component>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline reference get() noexcept;

        template<std::size_t component>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline const_reference get() const noexcept;

        template<vector_components component>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline reference get() noexcept;

        template<vector_components component>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline const_reference get() const noexcept;

...
```

`vector_components` is an `enum class`, used as eye sugar to access the first four components of a vector, defined as follows :

```cpp
    enum class vector_components : std::size_t {
        x = 0,
        y = 1,
        z = 2,
        w = 3
    };

    using vect_comp = vector_components;
```

When get is called with a `vector_component` argument, as follows:

```cpp
vector.get<math::vect_comp::x>()
```

Everything is fine. If the call is made with an integral value, as follows:

```cpp
vector.get<2>()
```

The call becomes ambiguous.

This seems to happen because the compiler can construct (or implicitly convert probably ) a `vector_components` from the passed in value.
If I were to remove the `std::size_t` overload, the second call would compile correctly (calling the `vector_components` version )(With some caveats when trying to construct it from a value that isn`t assigned to one of the enum values it seems ).

I think, but am unsure, that this may stem from something related to the fact that, while scoped enums do not implicitly convert to their underlying type, they can be initialized, in some circumstances ( that do not seem the one in my case, that is why I'm unsure ), [without a cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> Both scoped enumeration types and unscoped enumeration types whose underlying  type is fixed can be initialized from an integer without a cast, using list initialization, if all of the following is true:
>
> 1. the initialization is direct-list-initialization
> 2. the initializer list has only a single element
> 3. the enumeration is either scoped or unscoped with underlying type fixed
> 4. the conversion is non-narrowing

Now, while there are many compelling reasons to do something else instead of obsessing over this ambiguous call ( like dropping the overloads and just defining x, y, z, w as `constexpr std::size_t` values in an inner namespace or dropping this altogether ), I`m, nonetheless, quite curios on how to "best" resolve this conflict.

The only solution I could think of was the following:

```cpp
        template<typename U, U component, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>, std::size_t>, int> = 0>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline reference get() noexcept;

        template<typename U, U component, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>, std::size_t>, int> = 0>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline const_reference get() const noexcept;

        template<typename U, U component, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>, vector_components>, int> = 0>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline reference get() noexcept;

        template<typename U, U component, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>, vector_components>, int> = 0>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline const_reference get() const noexcept;
```

Which, apart from being uselessly complex, requires that the users explicitly express which one of the overloads he wants to call with the first parameter.

I would really like to understand, exactly, why this overload does not work and, secondarily, I`d like to know how such an overload could be made to work without the need for an explicit decision from the user.

Comment: What compiler are you using? A quick example appears to work with `GCC 8.2`: [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nOT_mc)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/5nPVlC Please provide a [mre].

Comment: "initialized from an integer without a cast, [*using list initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)": That's talking about `vector_components{ 0 }` or `vector_components component{ 0 };`, so that's probably not why.

Comment: @aschepler Ok, I was able to reproduce it https://godbolt.org/z/e8wvPk . It seems to happen only if I call the vector_components version with the vector_components that has the same value as the size_t call ( so z in the case of 2 ).

Comment: @LucaDiSera MSVC bug. Reduce the example a bunch and please submit a bug report.

Comment: @Barry Submitted. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems strange that call is ambiguous.

In C++17, you might "simplify"

```
template<typename U, U component, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>, std::size_t>, int> = 0>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline reference get() noexcept;
```

into

```
template <auto component, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(component)>>, std::size_t>, int> = 0>
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline reference get() noexcept;
```

And even probably with `if constexpr`:

```
template<auto component>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr inline reference get() noexcept
{
    using U = std::decay_t<decltype(component)>;

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, std::size_t>) {
        // ...
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, vector_components >) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Original code is ambiguous because 2 is a int literal and you are overloading on a size_t (which is unsigned) and an enum based on a size_t.

Comment: Shouldn't be ambiguous, because you can initialize a `size_t` from an `int`, but you can't initialize a scoped enumeration variable from an `int` (except in list initialization, which this isn't).